# What does the attribute `@EnvironmentObject` mean in the SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As you can see in the [official tutorial project](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views), there is this strange `@EnvironmentObject` placed before `var`. What does it mean?

```
struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    var landmark: Landmark

    var landmarkIndex: Int {
        userData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == landmark.id })!
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Related: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's for example for Network purposes. You have a class conforming to `BindableObject` (Beta 5: `ObservableObject`) and send through the `PassthroughSubject` (Beta 5: `@Published`) your data.

For example this case:

**SwiftUI (1.0)**

```
struct Course: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var courses = [Course]()

    func getAllCourses() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.courses = courses
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed To decode: ", error)
            }
        }.resume() // VERY IMPORTANT! As the request won't run
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
    // Or this
    // @EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager // Don't forget to instaniate it with .environmentObject()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.networkManager.getAllCourses()
            }, label: {
                Text("Get All Courses")
            })

            List(networkManager.courses, id: \.name) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Beta**

```
struct Course: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

class NetworkManager: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()

    var courses = [Course]() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    func getAllCourses() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.courses = courses
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed To decode: ", error)
            }
        }.resume() // VERY IMPORTANT! As the request won't run
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.networkManager.getAllCourses()
            }, label: {
                Text("Get All Courses")
            })

            List(networkManager.courses.identified(by: \.name)) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to play a bit with your example but I have these `Use of unresolved identifier 'PassthroughSubject'` and `Type 'NetworkManager' does not conform to protocol 'BindableObject'` errors.

Comment: You need to import Combine a new framework by apple

Comment: Oh sorry I havent noticed I forgot the import. Could you tell me more about the BindableObject protocol ? I have hard time to understand what it actually does... :/

Comment: @Que20 Please accept my answer. `@ObjectBinding` is an External reference property. Actually it is your data model that should be displayed.  `@EnvironmentObject` - the same as `@ObjectBinding`, but it uses across the environment to other views, while `@ObjectBinding` should passed explicitly

Comment: @Mint should accept your answer, Que20 wasn't the OP.  This is a great coding  example of EnvironmentObject

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS Thank you for your Beta5 example. Could you also provide how to instanciate **ContentView** now ? I was used to using `.environmentObject()` but no with @ObservedObject property wrapper it doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: @Hurobaki check the updated answer know. You can work with '@ObservedObject' the same way as '@ObjectBinding'

Comment: `List(networkManager.courses.identified(by: \.name)) {` fails with message `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: I have an issue my project was working fine, but today when I tried to check it, there was an empty list but in debugging area, there are data print

Comment: Thank a lot this save me lot of time. I was following all the old code with passthroughtsubject which doesn't work at all in latest betas.

Answer (score 1):

It’s designed to give your views access to the model automatically without the need for dependency injection.

Set the environment object once in the scene delegate then all views in the hierarchy have access to it via their own magic property. I believe it is also possible for a view to override the object for its children but I’ve not yet tested that yet.

Answer (score 0):

**EnvironmentObject**

I have found from apple document.

> **Description from apple:**
>
> A dynamic view property that uses a bindable object supplied by an
>   ancestor view to invalidate the current view whenever the bindable
>   object changes.

[apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject)

My understanding is when ever we set a value or object was init. Ex: List.
When we reload a List some showed View Objects are replaced and removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a BindableObject which SwiftUI will use to determine how to refresh your views via accessing the object. Check out the UserData class in the example. Any child of the view that declares the environmental object will have access to it. In this case `userData`.